# Defining variables with grunt-contrib-less

Tags: css, gruntjs, less

Unless I'm misunderstanding [this documentation](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less#usage-examples) it's possible to define a global `less` variable within your `Gruntfile` and reference it in your `.less` file (pretend there's a reason).

```
less: {
  modVar: {
    options: {
      plugins: [
        new (require('less-plugin-autoprefix'))
      ],
      modifyVars: {
        root: "<%= grunt.option('distRoot') %><%= grunt.option('distTarget') %>"
      },
      root: "<%= grunt.option('distRoot') %><%= grunt.option('distTarget') %>",
    },
    files: {
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.less' : '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*}*.less'
    }
  },
```

That (above) is my entry for the `Gruntfile`, and I'm trying to reference the variable `root` in one of my my `.less` files (main.less), but every time it's throwing an error in my console, "`@root is undefined`" in `main.less`. Am I misunderstanding what's possible with `grunt-contrib-less`? Or am I simply doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I figured it out. Had to tweak my less task in my `gruntfile` like so (based on the documentation/scouring the issues section):

```
less: {
  options: {
    compress: true,
    yuicompress: true,
    optimization: 2,
    modifyVars: {
      root: '"<%= grunt.option(\'distRoot\') %><%= grunt.option(\'distTarget\') %>"'
    }
  },
  /* blah, blah, blah...other less stuff.... */
}
```

So, rather than create a completely separate task for this variable modification I needed to simply throw the `modifyVars` option in the options section of my less task. More importantly (because I *had* tried that previously), was to wrap my variable's new value in single quotes **despite** having them already doubly-quoted. This was a huuuuuge headache to figure out.

Your variables should look like this:

```
 '"myWorkingValue"'
```

and **not** like this:

```
 "myNonWorkingValue"
```

And, for completeness, reference the variables in your `.less` file like so:

```
@{myModifiedVariable}
```

You should be set at this point.

Comment: Excellent, I was wondering why `modifyVars: { foo: 'bar' }` wasn't doing anything.